# Meta Messenger Send Messege API Set file name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm using Meta Messenger API to send a message to Messenger programmatically (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/attachment-upload-api) and is good. I'm able to send messages with and without attachments.

My issue is specific to messages with attachments. I'm able to successfully use the API but not able to set the file name of the attachment (in case the attachment is of type `file`).

How can I set a filename for the attachment so the recipient (Messenger user) can see it in the message thread ? Right now it seems the API automatically retrieve it from the url of the attachment. I'm using Azure Blob Storage, and the files are stored as GUID, and the true filename is stored in the `Content-Despotision` filename field.

Below is a sample call for reference.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/{fb.PageId}/messages?recipient={{'id':'{psid}'}}&messaging_type=RESPONSE&message={{'attachment':{{'type':'file','payload':{{'url':'{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(blobClient.Uri.ToString() + token)}','is_reusable':true" + "}}}" + $"&access_token={fb.PageToken}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, the last part of the payload url is used as the file name. Apparently, facebook API expects the url in the filesystem form (as Apache httpd would do), like: `https://example.com/files/folder/file.png`.

Here, `file.png` will be used as the attachment name. If your download API is named differently, like `.../resourceId/download`, you can adjust the route to accept `.../resourceId/download/{optionalFileName}` and process the request as before. Facebook API will catch the last part and use as the file name.

Example in Spring Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = {
        "/resources/{id}/download",
        "/resources/{id}/download/{fileNameForFbApi}"
}, produces = "application/octet-stream")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> downloadFile(
        @PathVariable long id,
        @PathVariable(required = false) String fileNameForFbApi
) {
    // ... process the request using only id
}
```